# C# windows form project

Tags: c#, winforms

Method of the 1st Form Class:

```
private void englishToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    var Editor = new Editor();
    Editor.Engprop = 1;
    Editor.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
    Editor.Show();
}
```

Method of the 2nd Form Class:

```
public partial class Editor : Form
{
    public int Engprop { get; set; }
    public Uri MyProperty { get; set; }
    public Editor()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

    }
    Uri temp = new Uri("file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/projese302/newtmp.html");
    Uri eng = new Uri("file:///C:/Users/PC/Desktop/projese302/engtemp.html");

    private void Editor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Engprop==1)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(eng);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to do that when `Engprop` becomes 1 (when a user clicks the item of the ToolStripMenu), it should navigate the `eng` URL but it doesn't work properly. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: _"but it doesn't work properly"_ What exactly does that mean? If the WebBrowser doesn't navigate to the target URL, [use the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019), see if the `webBrowser1.Navigate()` is reached, and/or check the value of `Engprop`.

Comment: As a side note, [do not use `Form.Closed` or `Form.Closing` events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closed?view=net-5.0#remarks) and use `Form.FormClosed` and `Form.FormClosing` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the Editor_Load method is called from the OnLoad event of the form.

If so, I'm not sure when this event is raised... Can be after the constructor (it explain why you have this problem) or after the Show method (in this case, I don't know why it doesn't work)

Try to check if the event is raised before or after you set the Engprop property (debug + breakpoints)

In any way, I think your code has a lack of architecture, since who use your Editor class need to know that can change the Engprop only between the constructor and the Show method.

I think you can make a better/reusable code if:

- Set the Engprop property as read only and accept his value in the constructor: this is usually done when the language is set when someone instantiate your class and will never change
- In the setter of the Engprop raise an event when it changes: this is done when you allow to change the language also after the instance is created. So, your Editor class can add an handler to this event and change the language of the page every time someone changes this property

Comment: The `Load` event occurs after calling `.Show()` in this case, not after the constructor. Or as Microsoft puts it: [_"Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time"_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=net-5.0).

Comment: I did a simple project with two forms: the main one that shows the second one as you did. And it always show the english version of the second form... so, what is the behaviour you have?

Comment: I'm not the OP :) I was just replying to your second paragraph of this answer.